# Get Image URL from JSON Retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, image, retrofit, picasso

every one, i am stuck in get ImageURL from REST API use Retrofit library in Android.My JSON SAMPLE IS:

```
[{
"Id": 549,
"Product Name": "COFFEE",
"Product Code": null,
"ImageUrl": "/Uploads/images/product\\549\\549.jpg",
"Unit Name": "LY",
"Unit": 57,
"Category": 37,
"Category Name": "COFFEE",
"Price": 18 usd
 }
 ]
```

**My POJO**

```
public class Food {
@SerializedName("Id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("Product Name")
@Expose
private String productName;
@SerializedName("Product Code")
@Expose
private String productCode;
@SerializedName("ImageUrl")
@Expose
private String imageUrl;
@SerializedName("UnitName")
@Expose
private String tenDonViTinh;
@SerializedName("Unit")
@Expose
private String unit;
@SerializedName("Category")
@Expose
private String category;
@SerializedName("Caegory Name")
@Expose
private String categoryName;
@SerializedName("Price")
@Expose
private String price;

get...set
```

**FoodAPI**

```
public interface FoodAPI {
String BASE_URL="http://dangbui.com"


@GET("")
Call
```

My Image URL doesn't have path .So,what i should GET and call to get Image? Please help me.Thank you so much!

Comment: sorry, i can't understand your question, pls give  some more details

Comment: you want complete data parsing in retrofit?

Comment: I have an array image of this like above "ImageUrl": "/Uploads/images/product\\549\\549.jpg" , i want to ask that what i must GET to show image in Recycle View .Thank

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function to return a URL in the API for image url, you are only getting the path where the image is stored and not the complete URL.

Comment: this is not what he is asking